# How do I add less to my Angular 2 CLI build?

Tags: angular, less, angular-cli

I have created a project with the Angular CLI and I would like to add less files to the build. I want a main less for shared and global styles and a less file in with the components for local styles. How can I add a compile less files step to the build process?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors

Comment: Add your global less files to 'styles' in .angular-cli.json, e.g. `"styles": [
        "my-style.less", "styles.css"]` as for the component less file, simply use `styleUrls: ['./component.less']`

Answer (score 9):

When creating a new project you can do `ng new project_name --style less`.

Comment: Do you know how to enable it post install?

Comment: It's been a while and I used sass. IIRC for sass I installed node-sass, renamed all css files to scss and their references. Then I added something in angular-cli.json, but you can also do `ng set defaults.styleExt scss`. Should be similar for less.

Comment: For post install, execute  npm install less --save and rename all CSS files in your component's directory to less.

Answer (score 8):

For post install, execute

```
npm install less --save
```

Then :
- rename all CSS files in your component's directory to less

- change ['./xxx.component.css'] by ['./xxx.component.less'] in every component file

Comment: Works for me. Thank you. Just one note. If your builder is already launched, for example through "ng serve", you need to restart it to apply changes.

Answer (score 6):

When generating a new project you can also define which extension you want for style files:

```
ng new less-project --style=less
```

Or set the default style on an existing project:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt less
```

;)

Comment: the `ng set` version seems to be deprecated now, it says:
`get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command.`

Answer (score 4):

Open .angular-cli.json file and add the path to your .less file in "styles" attribute.

For example.

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "_variables.less"
      ],
```

Answer (score 4):

We used the following command to update the default style type for our existing Angular project from `styl` to `less`.

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext less
```

The following snippet, take from our angular.json file, shows the change:

```
 "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "less"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For going from `css` to `less` for an existing Angular project, I found an article [here](https://dev.to/abuhasib/using-less-in-your-angular-9-project-5h0f) that does exactly what needed.